# Undefined variable in PHPStan but it's declared elsewhere

Tags: php, analysis, phpstan

How do you deal with these scenarios in PHPStan:

1. Say you're using plain PHP as template engine. E.g.,

> ```
> // view.php
>
> <b><?=$foo?></b>
> ```

---

2. Say you have 2 files `a.php` and `b.php`

> ```
> // a.php     
> $foo = 'bar';
>
> // b.php     
> require 'a.php';     
> echo $foo;
> ```

---

PHPStan will both report this as `Undefined variable: $foo`

How do you deal with this? Can PHPStan be configured to somehow execute your app so it knows that these variables are actually defined during runtime?

Comment: _"How do you deal with this?"_ By not doing that. If you want to use a value in b, don't rely on the assumption that it's been created in a. Instead, explicitly pass it as a parameter to a function/method.

Comment: PHPStan really works best with object oriented code and explicitly defined dependencies.

Comment: @AlexHowansky it's actually just a config/bootstrap file divided in to separate files for organization. I guess the only way is to simply just ignore it in phpstan settings.

Comment: _"just a config/bootstrap file"_ Doesn't matter, you've got a monolithic design that depends on global variables. PHPStan is right to alert on that. Put your configuration settings into an object, then pass that object to the things that need it. See [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: @AlexHowansky They are actually global constants but some comes from a .env file e.g., `$env = loadEnv('../.env'); define('FOO', $env['foo']);`

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use the `phpstan.neon` solution provided in [phpstan#104 (comment)](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/104#issuecomment-598412556):

You can ignore error for specific variables by using regular expressions, even in specific directories. In your case you can use:

```
parameters:
    ignoreErrors:
        -
            message: '#Undefined variable: \$foo.*#'
            path: my/directory/*
```

```
/** @var string $foo */

echo $foo; // No error

echo $unintededUndeclaredVariable; // Error
```

Comment: I was able to use this in my project like this: `message: '#Variable \$error might not be defined.#'`.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is perform a check to ensure the variable is set.

e.g.

```php
if (isset($foo)) {
    echo $foo;
}
```

or something like the following if you're not wanting to wrap all your code in an `if`.

```php
if (! isset($foo)) {
    throw new Exception('$foo not set');
}
```

Comment: Using this, will show "Unreachable statement - code above always terminate". There is an open Issue you all should be subscribed  https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/104#issuecomment-291877848

Comment: This assumes $foo is always not set, so the check is not useful in static analysis. You should set type as `/** @var string|null $foo */`