# PHPStan reports possibly undefined variable, but it's defined in included script

Tags: php, phpstan

I have an application where I define some variables in a file (`a.php`), then include this from another file (`b.php`). PHPStan is complaining about possibly undefined variables.

Simplified example:

a.php:

```php
$config['foo'] = 'bar';
```

b.php:

```php
<?php

require 'a.php';

//new SlimApp($config)->run();
echo $config;
```

PHPStan says:

```
------ ---------------------------------------- 
  Line   b.php                                   
 ------ ---------------------------------------- 
  :6     Variable $config might not be defined.  
 ------ ----------------------------------------
```

Also: I don't know why but if I remove the `<?php` line at the beginning of `b.php`, the warning goes away.

How can I have PHPStan realize that `$config` is actually defined?

Btw I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732413/undefined-variable-in-phpstan-but-its-declared-elsewhere). It is not the same problem as I am explicitly including the file where the variable is defined.

Comment: You cannot echo an Array! Could it just be that thats causing the message

Comment: Read the comment under/in your linked question that starts with "just a config/bootstrap file". Thats explains it good. And "might not" is not "not" defined.

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, that's not the problem

Comment: @Foobar No, the linked question does not explicitly `require` or `include` anything, it just relies on the variables being defined elsewhere. PHPStan cannot know that. This case is different.

Comment: @Grodriguez Ok, then try something like `/** @var array $config */` at the top of the file,  see: https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/5815

Comment: @Grodriguez Also i have seen your Bug Report, may you have found something that needs to be fixed. But  i thing PHPStan works best on OOP style projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Solution:

Yo can prevent the notice with `/** @var array $config */` at the top of the file.

See for more information here: https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/5815